# Extracting specific lines of text based on a single line of text using Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have below lines in a huge text file and want to extract LineD and other lines in front of it. If the set does not contains Line D, it should ignore the set

```
LineA
LineB 
LineC

Line1
Line2 
Line3
LineD

Linex
LineY 
LineZ

Line4
Line5 
Line6
LineD
```

Output should be

```
Line1
Line2 
Line3
LineD

Line4
Line5 
Line6
LineD
```

Comment: Please format your question and show us the actual text, not what you have shown above.

Comment: This sounds like a job for regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:\A|\R\R)(?:(?!LineD)[\s\S])*?(?=\R\R|\z)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:\A|\R\R)     # non capture group, beginning of file OR 2 linebreaks
(?:             # non capture group
  (?!LineD)     # negative lookahead, make sure sure we haven't "LineD"
  [\s\S]        # any character, including linebreak
)*?             # end group, may appear 0 or more times, not greedy
(?=\R\R|\z)     # positive lookahead, make sure we have a double linebreak OR end of file after.
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]